# Note down pages modified from page fault traps

Tags: c, linux, x86-64

I have an application, which periodically takes checkpoints (each 1 or 2 seconds). The checkpoint is taken by using `fork`. For some reason, I also need to note down pages which have been modified since the last checkpoint. The most efficient way that comes to my mind is that we can note down the pages whenever there is a page fault due to copy-on-write mechanism used in fork, where initially (immediately after fork) the same physical pages are mapped to the original and forked process, but when the original process tries to write to a page, a new physical page is mapped for that page address.

I think, I will need to make modifications in the kernel to do this, or can this be done in user space, by using some signal handler? At this moment what I was doing was to make all pages used by the application read only after taking a checkpoint, and trap the faults by using a signal handler when pages are written to note down their addresses. However, this is inefficient as compared to noting down pages on copy-on-write. How can I achieve that. What part of kernel do I need to modify? Can someone provide me the link to that part of the code where I need to make the modifications? And also can someone advise me if this can be done in userspace with the same or nearly same efficiency?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but `fork` is not sufficient for checkpointing non-trivial applications...